# What is the best way to power a wearable device such as flexible oled screens?

Tags: power-supply, power, oled, wearable

What is the best way to power a wearable device such as flexible oled screens? Possibly a way that wouldnt alter the size of the wearable?

Comment: Without more information about what the power requirements, size requirements and run time might be it's not a question that is possible to answer.

Answer (score 8):

1. *No charging:* A bio reactor hooked into the wearer's blood stream.
2. *High Tech:* A thorium salt nuclear reactor.
3. *Green:* A wind turbine on the wearer's hat.
4. *Well marketable:* Microscopic solar panels woven into a jacket.
5. *Meaningful:* A battery.

---

You see what this is about. Be specific.

Comment: aww man, I was going to go for the nasty comment but this wins

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer this as if the question is really, "**How to determine battery size needed for wearable device product design**".

I'm also assuming a product worn on the wrist, similar to a wristwatch, though there are other types of wearable applications -- the basic development process steps are the same.

First you need to estimate the **power budget** for your device. How many power supply voltage rails, and how much current is needed for each supply (based on the max operating supply current ratings from the data sheet for each component). Determine the maximum current during peak demand, as well as the minimum current (or `quiescent` current) when the system is idle. Estimate the average power consumption based on what % of the time is full-power.

Design the power regulator system to develop all of the needed voltage rails from a single main power supply (from a battery), which will combine all of the load currents. **Linear regulators** are great for draining every last bit of energy from a battery, though they suffer from inherently limited efficiency

$$ \frac{V_{in} - V_{out}} {V_{in}} $$

They also dissipate (waste) power equal to

$$ \frac{V_{in}- V_{out}}{I_{out}} $$

and heat dissipation is of concern in a wearable product, especially if it will be worn close to the skin. So if there is a large difference between battery voltage and device supply voltage, and significant current load, this could be a problem. **Switch-Mode Power Supplies** (SMPS) such as `buck regulator` or `step-down regulator` are more efficient and tend to draw nearly constant power, so as the battery voltage decreases, the supply current must increase. These are more versatile and more efficient, but also more complicated to design and use. Depends on your exact application. That's a whole different topic. (*Disclosure: I work at Maxim Integrated, one of several companies that manufacture Power Management Integrated Circuits (PMIC) for applications such as these.*)

If at all possible, it's good to build a **functional prototype** of the electronics, to help supplement the power budget with experimental measurements. This helps prove your product could work, and will be useful later when you try to determine if there's any way to trade features for lower power.

**Batteries** come in many different case sizes and capacities. Generally a larger battery can supply higher voltage and/or more power and energy. Remember that power is energy per unit time. Battery capacity (available energy) is often given in units of mAh (miliAmpere-Hours): for example, a 550mAh battery should be able to supply a 1mA load for 550 hours, or supply a 10mA load for approximately 55 hours, or a 500mA load for approximately 1 hour. Obviously this approximation doesn't work at extreme cases; at the low end there is `leakage current` and at the high end there is output limitation due to internal `source impedance`. At some point the battery voltage may become too low to operate your device, this `end-of-discharge` point may happen before the mAh estimate -- check the discharge curves in the battery data sheet. But it's still a useful heuristic for comparing different batteries.

So once you have determined how many mA of load current your device requires, and also determined how many hours of operation the device must run, multiply the two to find how many mAh of battery capacity you want.

Next, hit the web search engine and start downloading **battery data sheets**. Start with commonly available consumer batteries for **hearing aid** (such as `zinc-air size 10a battery`) and **wristwatch** applications (such as `CR2032` or `CR2016`). These are `primary batteries`, batteries that come fully charged at the factory and that must be replaced by the consumer when fully discharged. You may also consider **rechargeable** `secondary batteries` which require a power control system to recharge the device. Either way, stick with the major brand-name battery manufacturers (duracell.com, eveready.com, rayovac.com, sony.com etc.) because their data sheets are easier to find and easier to read, and their product is more widely available. See how large a battery is needed to give the desired runtime.

Most likely, you won't be happy with the available choices, because long battery life usually requires a larger, heavier battery, and that's not good for a wearable device. This may require re-evaluating your initial prototype design requirements -- **if the wearable device is too big or too heavy**, or requires an expensive or unconventional battery, **it won't be a viable product.** So you may have to consider removing some product features to trim down the power budget. This isn't trivial, but it is an essential part of product development.

Ultimately, it's all about negotiating parts cost, development cost, feature set, size and weight, runtime, and even internal and external politics, to finally find a satisfactory product design.